# Clojure equivalent to Python's "any" and "all" functions?

Tags: python, clojure

Are there built in functions in Clojure similar to Python's `any` and `all` functions?

For example, in Python, it's `all([True, 1, 'non-empty string']) == True`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`(every? f data)` <sup>[[docs](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/every?)]</sup> is the same as `all(f(x) for x in data)`.

`(some f data)` <sup>[[docs](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/some)]</sup> is like `any(f(x) for x in data)` except that it returns the value of `f(x)` (which must be truthy), instead of just `true`.

If you want the exact same behaviour as in Python, you can use the `identity` function, which will just return its argument (equivalent to `(fn [x] x)`).

```clj
user=> (every? identity [1, true, "non-empty string"])
true
user=> (some identity [1, true "non-empty string"])
1
user=> (some true? [1, true "non-empty string"])
true
```

Comment: I think usin identity function instead of new anonymous one would be better. eg (every? identity [1, true, "non-empty-string"]), (some identity [1,  true, "non-empty-string"])...

Comment: +1 for Verneri's comment about using identity. It's more idiomatic.

Comment: That's not quite what one might expect. (some f data) returns neither true nor false, but, as Jeremy said, the first value of f(x) that Clojure takes as true, NOT the true symbol. On the other hand, if no f(x) out of all x from data evaluate to true, (some) returns nil, NOT the false symbol. In order to behave like every?, further processing is needed, e.g. (true? (some f data)). PS: (some true? data) does still not work, because it returns nil for no matches.

Comment: Also, `(some true? data)` is not the `any` you'd expect coming from python: `(some true? [1 [true] "non-empty-string"])` yields a falsy value

Answer (score 4):

In clojure `and` and `or` are quite similar to python's `all` and `any`, with the caveat that (just like `clojure.core/some`) they return the element that will satifsy it... thus you can use it together with `boolean` to convert it

```
(boolean (or "" nil false)) ; "" is truthy in clojure
; => true
(boolean (and [] "" {} () 0)) ; also [], {}, () and 0 are truthy
; => true
```

I use `boolean` instead of `true?` since the latter will return `true` iff the argument is the value true... so `boolean` is more akin to python's `bool` in that it evaluates the truthyness

Unlike `some` & `every?`, `and` & `or` are macros, so if you always want to convert the result to a boolean, you cannot simply do `(def any (comp boolean or))` but you have to define a macro like

```
(defmacro any [& v] `(boolean (or ~@v)))
(defmacro all [& v] `(boolean (and ~@v)))
```

a side-effect/advantage of being macros, is that they are lazy/can shortcircuit (just like python's `and` & `or`, that are infix binary operators however)

```
(any "" (/ 1 0))
; => true
(all nil (/ 1 0))
; => false
```

and they're just like python's `any` and `all`, even when called without arguments

```
(any)
; => false
(all)
; => true
```

in python:

```
>>> any([])
False    
>>> all([])
True
```

If you prefer to have to call `any`/`all` with a single list/sequence argument, you can simply do:

```
(defmacro all [v] `(boolean (and ~@v)))

(all [])
; => true
(all [nil (/ 1 0)])    
; => false
```